# Can't stream to VLC from my Conceptronic IP Camera (RTSP)

Tags: url, stream, vlc, rtsp, ip-camera

I have a **Conceptronic CIPCAM720OD**, which works and records just fine. I use its own software to see the picture on my computer, and the App to see the video stream on my smartphone.

I tried **streaming its output to VLC Media Player** through two devices (my **Windows laptop**, and my **Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu MATE**) in the same local network, but I always get the same error in the error log:

```
live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://192.168.1.250:554/11
access_realrtsp error: cannot connect to 192.168.1.250:554
core error: open of `rtsp://192.168.1.250:554/11' failed
```

At first glance I thought I got the IP or the Port wrong, but then I checked in the settings of my camera's software: This is the correct IP Address (**192.168.1.250**) and Port number (**554**), and **RTSP is enabled**.

It still seemed like a network problem, so then I tried disabled all the routers' firewalls on my local network just to test and I get the same error.

I confirmed that the camera does offer RTSP streaming to a specific URL after reading the [user manual](http://download.conceptronic.net/manuals/CIPCAM720PTIWL,CIPCAM720OD,CIPCAM720ODWDR,CIPDCAM720OD-V1_UM_V1.0.pdf), and even tried changing the URL to couple different ones after consulting [this website](https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Conceptronic), but I keep getting this in my error log.

What could I be forgetting, or what be the issue?

EDIT: I corrected the right IP address (it was .158 for the longest time, but very recently I updated it to .250 due to DHCP issues).

Now, I'm getting a login/password prompt window from VLC, that returns 401 Unauthorized when I put the correct username / password.

I made sure I inserted the correct username / password (I use the same in the camera's software, and in the camera's mobile App - I tested in both iOS and Android).

Here's what Wireshark is telling me (Note: .104 is my PC):

[image: Wireshark's log]

Here's an inspection of the 401 error:

[image]

Comment: Is the port open at all? Use Wireshark to understand what is going on at network level. Maybe it is just a network configuration issue? Maybe the camera expects some specific headers (I've seen cameras that require specific `User-Agent` values to work). Wireshark should help.

Comment: Gonna try that. I already made sure that the port is open (in the camera's software server settings) and even tried disabling the firewall to ensure it wasn't blocking.

Comment: Ok, so I made a mistake - .158 was the old IP. I had changed (very recently) it due to DHCP problems in my LAN, but forgot. I also followed your advice and checked out Wireshark. I updated the original post with more details.

Comment: One more thing: I'm actually trying to get Ubuntu Motion to run with this camera. I figured connecting it to VLC should be the first step (to get its net url & address info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I followed Rudolfs's suggestion and traced the correct URL from the Wireshark logs.

As it turns out, the correct IP address is NOT the one given in the manual, or [in this website](https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Conceptronic), but instead was this one:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.250:554/live/ch0
```

Now everything is up and running correctly.

Thanks to Rudolfs for the help and time spent!